# How to pass DocumentSnapshot Id between two classes?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have two dropdown menu's. One Represent the Category and Other Represent the Sub Category. The values should be retrieved from firesotore. Where the collection is created as a Nested Collection.

[Categories & SubCategories collection are shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVwK5.jpg)

```
class SelectCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SelectCategoryState createState() => _SelectCategoryState();
}

class _SelectCategoryState extends State<SelectCategory> {
  AdminDatabaseMethods adminDatabaseMethods = AdminDatabaseMethods();
  var selectedCategory;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: adminDatabaseMethods.getCategories(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          List<DropdownMenuItem> categoryMenu = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.data.docs.length; i++) {
            DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];
            categoryMenu.add(DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(snap.data()["Category_Name"]),
              value: "${snap.id}",
            ));
            //adminDatabaseMethods.getSubCategories(snap);

          }
          return DropdownButton(
            value: selectedCategory,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_downward_sharp,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
            iconSize: 20,
            elevation: 16,
            hint: Text(
              "Select Main Categories",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
            ),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
            underline: Container(
              height: 2,
              color: Colors.amber[300],
            ),
            onChanged: (categoryValue) {
              setState(() {
                selectedCategory = categoryValue;
                adminDatabaseMethods.getSubCategories(selectedCategory);
              });
            },
            items: categoryMenu,
          );
        });
  }
}
```

This is how I have created the list of Categoires and followed the same way to create the subcategories. What I require is I when i press the category I need to pass the documentsnapshot id to the other class.
Where,

```
Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 15,
                  ),
                  SelectCategory(),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 15,
                  ),
                  SelectsubCategories(),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 15,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Categories and Sub Categories are given like this. Is there a way of passing the data. As i am new to flutter please suggest me a method thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a state management solution. Learn more [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro).